# Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T1'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Why does the object `{ a: number; }` can not assignable to type 'T1' ?

Code below:

```js
type T = { a: number };

class A<T1 extends T> {
    constructor(public x: T1 = { a: 1 }){}
};
```

```
Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T1'.
  '{ a: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T1', 
  but 'T1' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'T'.
```

- [**REPL**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwG4AoKgYwBtUBnJqAQQB4YBGKCAD2AQsAE1YwAfMipRZUWgHssTYMRy1gC4gAowOAvQCWtKP0w8EyNJl5kAlEjJVKQA)

Comment: You left out the rest of the message: "'{ a: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T1', but 'T1' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'T'."

Comment: One cannot assign a T value to a T1 variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple. Here `T1` is an extension of `T`, so anything that is a `T1` is also a `T`, but not conversely. Depending on what `T1` is, `{a:1}` may not be assignable to `T1`. Consider this example:

```
type TT = T & {b:string};
new A<TT>();
```

What will happen in the constructor then? Since you didn't pass the parameter `x`, it will use the default value `{a:1}` for `x`, but clearly `{a:1}` is not a `TT`.

Comment: A better code below: `constructor(public x: T1 = { a: 1 } as T1){}`, but I do not know that why does the `{ a: 1 }` can not assignable to the `T1`?

Comment: why dose the object `{ a: 1 }` is not `T1`? if the code is `new A({ a: 1 });`, it is correctly.

Comment: @Michael_Lee You can certainly use type assertion to block (not fix!) the error, but depending on the rest of the code that may simply result in runtime error.

Comment: @Michael_Lee Let me put it in another way: because `T1` may have extra requirements that `{a:1}` fails to satisfy.

Comment: In the example `new A({ a: 1 });`, TypeScript will automatically infer `T` as exactly `{a:number}` and thus indeed there is no error. But consider the `TT` example above, and you should be able to see why it is not allowed.